# Animation is not smooth on devices

Tags: android, ios, unity-game-engine

I want to animate a texture by changing uvRect.y of RawImage.

```
public class animation : MonoBehaviour {

public RawImage image;
public Text text;

private Rect rect;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    Application.targetFrameRate = 60;
    rect = image.uvRect;
}

// Update is called once per frame
void FixedUpdate () {
    rect.y += (Time.fixedDeltaTime*0.1f);
    text.text = (Time.fixedDeltaTime * 0.1f).ToString() + "  :   " + Time.fixedDeltaTime + "  :  "+image.uvRect.y;
    image.uvRect = rect;
}
}
```

In Unity's editor animation is smooth, but on devices (iOS or Android) it's not.
There are no other scripts in the scene so CPU is not loaded so much to make animation not smooth.

So why it's so and how to fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because you using `FixedUpdate()`. Try to use `Update()` instead. FixedUpdate should be used to physics operations.

You should also chande `Time.fixedDeltaTime` to `Time.deltaTime`.

`FixedUpdate` depends on physic steps that you can setup in editor. But `Update` is based on FPS so your animation will be smoother than in `FixedUpdate`.